# datatable is not being responsive

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have created two tables both are same. I am also using the responsive feature of the datatable for making it responsive. I display one table at a time and show and hide them on basis of two radio buttons which i created. The issue is that whenever i switch between the tables if one is responsive then the other is not.
The table images
[image: Table one]
When i click on radio button to change the table 2 is not showing that '+' button when you change the size of browser table 2 gets responsive but when you switch table again then you find that table 1 is not responsive with '+' button missing.
[image: Table two]

Here is the head and to change between tables script

```
<link data-require="datatables@1.10.12" data-semver="1.10.12" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script data-require="datatables@1.10.12" data-semver="1.10.12" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="datatables-responsive@*" data-semver="2.1.0" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({


            responsive: true


        });
        $('#example1').DataTable({


            responsive: true


        });
        iniTable();
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });            

        $("input[name='DeviceType']").change(function () {
            var rbVal = $('input[name=DeviceType]:checked').val();
            $("#Loader").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            if (rbVal == "PID") {

                $("#example").hide(500);
                $("#example1").show(500);
            }
            else {

                $("#example1").hide(500);
                $("#example").show(500);

            }
        });
    });

    function iniTable() {
        var $radios = $('input:radio[name=DeviceType]');
        if ($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
            $radios.filter('[value=PID]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }


    $(".close").on("click", function () {
        $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Here is the body

```
 <div id="radiobtn">
    <div style="margin-top:6px;">
        <label class="control-label">
            Device Type
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input name="DeviceType" type="radio" id="rbTypeCID" class="form-controlnoborder radio-inline" style="border: none;" value="CID">
            </span>
            <label class="form-control">CID</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input name="DeviceType" type="radio" id="rbTypePID" class="form-controlnoborder radio-inline" style="border: none;" value="PID" checked="checked">
            </span>
            <label class="form-control">PID</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="display:none; width:100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>           
        <tr>

            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
            <td>7580</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
            <td>1042</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
            <td>2120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
            <td>6222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
            <td>9383</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
            <td>8327</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
            <td>2927</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
            <td>8352</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
            <td>7439</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
            <td>4389</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
            <td>3431</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
            <td>3990</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
            <td>1016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is table 2 It is same just different id

```
<table id="example1" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>           
        <tr>

            <td>Hope</td>
            <td>Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
            <td>6318</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
            <td>7580</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
            <td>1042</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
            <td>2120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
            <td>6222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
            <td>9383</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
            <td>8327</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
            <td>2927</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
            <td>8352</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
            <td>7439</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
            <td>4389</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
            <td>3431</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
            <td>3990</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
            <td>1016</td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I just followed suggestion by @finw3 to use

```
$('#example1').DataTable().collapse.adjust();
```

It is working but table is getting resize, the column 1 occupies the whole browser [image: Table one]

Comment: create a fiddle it would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have hidden tables when Datatables initializes you may need to use `columns.adjust()` to recalc the columns when the tab is activated.

```
if (rbVal == "PID") {
  $("#wrap1").hide(500);
  $("#wrap2").show(500);
  $('#example1').DataTable().columns.adjust();
} else {
  $("#wrap2").hide(500);
  $("#wrap1").show(500);
  $('#example').DataTable().columns.adjust();
}
```

I wrap the tables on divs. So the paginative & filter inputs are hidden too.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zhypvhmk/15/)

Comment: Hi, I just copied your code from fiddle an ran it in my browser , it does work but not like in fiddle. After i click the radio button The 1st column of table 2 occupies the whole page and on switching back same thing happens